# Can you host a ServiceStack Web App in IIS?

Tags: iis, .net-core, servicestack

I have made a ServiceStack Web App that uses a custom AppHost from a plugin (similar to the example https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/WebApp/tree/master/src/apps/chat). I can run it on macOS with the dotnet command as per the examples.

Can I host my Service Stack Web App on IIS? What approach should I take? Reverse-proxying Kestrel like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

or will I need to have different AppHost/Startup code for the two hosting situations?

Or maybe there's a fundamental reason why it will never work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebApp is a standard .NET Core 2.0 App](https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/WebApp/blob/master/src/WebApp/Program.cs) so you'll be able to host it as you would any other .NET Core App. Normally reverse proxies don't require anything except the [internal url where the request is proxied to](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/deploying-web-apps#setup-nginx), but it looks like IIS wants you to explicitly call `.UseIISIntegration()` which is an issue that may have prevented the existing WebApp binary as it didn't call .NET Core 2.0 `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` which among other things would turn on `IISIntegration` when the .NET Core App is hosted in IIS/Windows which is now being done from [this commit](https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/WebApp/commit/2c438f39e67f46b65cf5fe8a74c07808c480a261).

You can find the updated Web App binaries with this change in the `/web` folder of the https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/Chat project.